# parenthesis and brackets in javascript

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

i am currently trying our the cordova sqlite for my application to retrieve data from an sqlite table.  I have the following code to select all customer information:

```
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM customerinformation WHERE lastName LIKE ? AND firstName LIKE ? ", [ lastName, firstName ], function(rs) {
        if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
            var response = {};
            if (rs.rows.item) {
                response.data = rs.rows.item;
            } else {
                response.data = [{}];
            }
            successCallback(response);
        } else {
            alert('No Record Found');
        }
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```

Now, if I access the response.data[0], i get undefined.  However, if i try response.data(0), i can see the object for the customer information.  How do i transfer the rs.rows.item into the response.data array?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to make this work with the following changes:

```
    db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM customerinformation WHERE lastName LIKE ? AND firstName LIKE ? ", [ lastName, firstName ], function(rs) {
        if (rs.rows.length > 0) {
            var response = {};
            response.data = [{}];
            if (rs.rows.item) {
                for (i=0;i<rs.rows.length; i++) {
                response.data[i] = rs.rows.item(i);
                }
            }
            successCallback(response);
        } else {
            alert('No Record Found');
        }
    }, function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    });
```